# Creation of data in a :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'll ask my question first:

Will this code logically work and it is the right thing to do (best practices perspective)? First off, it looks strange having a user being passed to a static subscription method

User and magazine have a many to many relationship through subscriptions (defined below). Also you can see, I've used through joins instead of the has and belongs to many so that we can define a subscription model.

after creating a user they need to have default subscriptions. Following the single responsibility principle, I don't think a user should have to know what default magazines to subscribe to. So how, after a user has been created can I create default subscriptions. The user.likes_sports? user.likes_music? should define which subscriptions methods we want.

Am I on the right track? I don't have anyone to review my code, any code suggestions highly appreciated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create create_default_subscriptions

    has_many :magazines, :through => :subscriptions
    has_many :subscriptions

    def create_default_subscriptions
        if self.likes_sports?
          Subscription.create_sports_subscription(self)
      end
    end
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :magazine

   #status field defined in migration

   def self.create_sports_subscription(user)
     Magazine.where("category = 'sports'").find_each do |magazine|
       user.subscriptions << Subscription.create(:user => user, :magazine => magazine, :status=>"not delivered")
     end
   end
   .
   .
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base    
   has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
   has_many :subscriptions
end
```

Comment: Would you like to add methods to your user to check if the user  `likes_sports?` or what would you like to do? Just create some other records after the creation of your user?

Comment: Did an edit, question is at the top of post

Answer (score 1):

The code is too coupled in my view. This can get out of hand really easily.

The right way to do this in my view would be to create a new service/form that takes care of creating the user for you

```
class UserCreationService

  def perform
    begin
      create_user
    # we should change this to only rescue exceptions like: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid or so.
    rescue => e
      false
    end
  end

  private

  def create_user
    user = nil
    # wrapping all in a transaction makes the code faster
    # if any of the steps fail, the whole user creation will fail
    User.transaction do
      user = User.create
      create_subscriptions!(user)
    end
    user
  end

  def create_subscriptions!(user)
    # your logic here
  end
end
```

Then call the code in your controller like so:

```
def create
  @user = UserCreationService.new.perform
  if @user
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "success"
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "erererererooooor"
  end
end
```

Comment: It is nice to hear another perspective, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome :). We use form objects for almost everything.